# Create border around a centered custom view and removing useless LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view, border

Currently I have following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/editorRootView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout android:id="RL1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- LinearLayout needed so we have an border outside of the EditorView -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="LL1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <xenolupus.EditorView
                android:id="@+id/editorView"
                android:layout_width="300dip"
                android:layout_height="216dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/otherImage"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:text="@string/cardEditor_OtherImageButtonText" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:text="@string/cardEditor_NextButtonText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the used @drawable/border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid 
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke 
        android:width="10dip" 
        android:color="#FF0099CA" />
    <padding 
        android:left="10dip" 
        android:top="10dip" 
        android:right="10dip"
        android:bottom="10dip" />
    <corners 
        android:radius="5dip" />
</shape>
```

However Eclipse warns me (yellow triangle with !) that the LinearLayout LL1 in the RelativeLayout RL1 is useless and should be removed:

> This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless;
>   transfer the background attribute to the other view.

As the RelativeLayout is needed to center the EditorView I tried removing the LinearLayout LL1 and adding the android:background of the LinearLayout LL1 to the EditorView. However doing lets the border disappear behind the content of the EditorView.

Is there another way to add a border outside of the EditorView or should I just ignore the warning?

Greetings
Xeno Lupus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    yes it's right, put the background inside your <xenolupus.EditorView 
        like this    
<xenolupus.EditorView
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/editorView"
                    android:layout_width="300dip"
                    android:layout_height="216dip" />

    and then  add gravity to it parent the RL1 layout  

    > android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

View can draw background by default. If you developed you `EditorView` correctly, you can just set background and paddings directly in XML:

```
<xenolupus.EditorView
    android:id="@+id/editorView"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="216dip"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

By "developed correctly" I mean that your view calculate it's width in height (in `onMeasure` or `onSizeChanged` methods) **with** paddings. In other words: while calculating size you used `getPadding*()` methods.

**NOTE**

Do not forget to call `super.onDraw()` !